# Удвоенное С в словах "расчет" и "рассчитывать"

Tags: орфография, удвоенные-буквы

И слово "расчет", и слово "рассчитывать" происходят от слова "считать". Почему же в одном случае (рассчитывать) пишется удвоенная С, а в другом (расчет) - нет?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

В словах с корнем "-чет-" пишется одно С: приставка "рас-" и корень "-чет-". Исключение - слово "бессчетный".
Примеры: *расчет, счетный, расчетливость*.
В словах с корнем "-счит-" пишется два С: приставка "рас-" и корень "-счит-".
Пример: *рассчитать*.
Для удобства запоминания нужно помнить, что, если в корне пишется буква е (ё), то С будет одна, если И - то две (только, если приставка заканчивается на С).

Answer (score 1):

Корни **чит** и **счит** разные. По смыслу разные. Один - про "принимать во внимание" (и оттуда глагол учитывать, например), другой - про калькуляции.

Поэтому - *рассчитывать* налог, но *расчитывать* на помощь, с одной **с**!

Comment: *Корни чит и счит разные... расчитывать на помощь, с одной с!* - Приведите, пожалуйста,  хоть какое-нибудь обоснование этой вашей идеи.

Answer (score 0):

Меня также всегда интересовал этот вопрос. Рассчитывать – это выполнить расчет.  Непонятно, почему в этих словах пишется разное количество  С. Подходящее объяснение мне хотелось бы представить участникам форума и послушать их критику.

1. Прежде всего рассмотрим видовую пару глаголов *честь – читать*, их исходное значение – работа с информацией.
2. С глаголом *честь* соотносится целая группа приставочных глаголов и образованных от них существительных: *счесть – счет, расчесть – расчет, вычесть – вычет, зачесть – зачет, перечесть – перечет.*
3. Эти глаголы различаются по смыслу, например: *счесть* – это воспринять информацию, а *расчесть* – это воспринять и расшифровать информацию.
4. Среди этих глаголов выделяются глаголы с более узким значением:  *считать* – работать с числами и *читать* – воспринимать буквенную информацию.
5. От глагола *считать* (НВ) образуется глагол *рассчитать* (СВ) и *рассчитывать* (НВ), при этом глаголы *расчесть* (СВ)  и *рассчитывать* (СВ) близки по смыслу.
6. Согласно толковым словарям,  существительное *расчет* соотносится с обоими глаголами (*расчесть и рассчитать*), но образуется от глагола *расчесть*.
7. Семантика существительного считывается с его морфемного состава, так как **приставка РАС передает смысл подробного анализа информации** (нет необходимости в наличии второй приставки С, которая присутствует в графической форме *рассчет*).

Comment: Потому, что счет/счит и чет - это разные корни.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваше мнение, оно мне всегда интересно. А как Вы ответите на эти вопросы: 1) Почему в существительном "расчет" пишется одна С? 2) Как оно образовано? 3) Почему толковые словари относят "расчет" как к глаголу "расчесть", так и к глаголу "рассчитывать"?

Comment: @behemothus: Окей, но как понять, в каком слове какой корень? Вообще не вижу логики.

Comment: Логика тут очевидная. На современном этапе в счет/счит  приставка не выделяется, да и в историческом плане все неочевидно. Например, такой факт. Считать - глагол несовершенного вила, а значит бесприставочный. Если считать С в считать приставкой, то удаление её не должно менять семантику морфа (не просто уточнять), что тоже не так. Читать и читать - это совершенно разные действия. И т.д. А уж как определить... А в каком случае их можно спутать? Только в самом корне "счет" разве... Ну я сказал, трудно тут приставку С выделить на фоне "отсчет" или "обсчет".

Comment: Таким образом какие-то сомнения может вызвать единственное слово "расчет". Но тут уж надо ориентироваться на "историческую справедливость". Изначально оно означало не производство неких вычислений, и даже не выявление некоей пользы или целесообразности, основания  ("расчет был на то, что хищение заметят не сразу")  а толкование базирующееся на разделения чего-то по принципу четности (чет и нечет). Чего тут еще можно обсуждать - даже не знаю...  Vera явно чего-то переструктурировала, за систематикой этой цели не видно..

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Почему в существительном "расчет" пишется одна С?

Потому, что корень "чет" (четный, чета)

> 2) Как оно образовано?

Рас - приставка, чет - корень.

> 3) Почему толковые словари относят "расчет" как к глаголу "расчесть", так и к глаголу "рассчитывать"?

Если "почему" здесь вообще уместно, то именно потому, что они, как и большинство специальных (не этимологических и не исторических) словарей придерживаются синхронистического подхода. "Счит" и "чет" рассматриваются как как два фактически различных корня - по современному состоянию, т.к. произошло переразложение (вернее сказать: консолидация исторической приставки "c" c корнем "чет/чит").
И словарям ничего не остается как сопоставлять единственную порождающую форму для обоих глаголов.

В диахронии же счит<c+чет/чит - с чередованием корневого гласного в зависимости от места ударения. И "рассчитать" в историческом плане имеет две приставки современную "рас" и древнюю, консолидировавшуюся в корень - "с".

Но вообще-то это уже - "опционально", для практического понимания ситуации не требуется. 
Первых двух пунктов вполне, думаю, достаточно чтобы понять суть на школьном уровне.

Comment: На школьном уровне правило легко запомнить, на не школьном - хотелось бы его объяснить.  Меня интересует схема словообразования: скорее всего, "расчесть - расчёт", но не "рассчитать - расчет". Только  о глаголе "расчесть" никто не вспоминает, а вопросы вызывает следующее сопоставление: считать - счёт, рассчитать - расчёт, почему не "рассчёт"? В этом примере, как нигде, хотелось бы знать значение каждой буквы.

Answer (score -2):

Нет правил, нет исключений. Логичнее было бы сравнить *отчёт* и *отсчёт*. Что в основе: *читать* или *считать*? *Прочитанный* маршрут или *просчитанный* маршрут? Правила пишут люди, а не боги. Человеку свойственно ошибаться. Обе формы написания должны иметь право на существование.

Comment: Ответа не вижу. Даже попытки дать таковой. Разговоры при "читать" и "считать" - от лукавого. Это исторически далекие друг от друга корни: *(с)чет* и *чит*. К тому же слова, пишущиеся через -(чИт-) 0 а оно там всегда ударное, - никаких сложностей в правописании не вызывают.  Чит и счит - настолько далеки по смыслы, что из трулно спутать, а значит и ошибиться в количесве С.